# Search menu zoomed in

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-search

I have recently adjusted my setup (can't have enough monitors, right?). I changed my primary display to one of my external monitors, but now I have one small, but very challenging issue.  My search menu is zoomed in. (see screenshot below)

[image]

I have tried opening this with the shortcut `win + s`,  adjusting my screen resolution, restarting the system, and compared to other menus (ie. main window menu) and everything is working except the search menu.

Any solutions or troubleshooting steps are greatly appreciated.

(if you don't have something productive to add, please troll elsewhere)

**ADDED SCREENSHOT PER @LPChip's Comment**

[image]

Comment: Look into your DPI setting. I bet it is set to like 200% or something.

Comment: @LPChip - Thank you for that suggestion, I did look at that with my resolution (unless there is another place to set that (see additional screen shot in question)

Comment: The DPI setting is a, per-monitor setting. Ensure that you click the monitor the start menu will appear on first, then see what the DPI and resolution is. That said, if I compare your screenshot to my own search window, they appear to be the same size.

Comment: @LPChip - Yes, I was adjusting the resolution and zoom etc. the correct screen.  If you are having the same issue on the Search Menu then maybe this is a Windows issue. Does your Windows menu look ok?

Comment: It looks okay on my 3440x1440 resolution. Normal proportion, although it is indeed a bit big. I don't use search anyway so for me not a problem.

Comment: @LPChip - Ok, so any idea on a solution for those of us that do like typing app names?

Comment: I usually just press start (or windows key) and then start typing.

Comment: @LPChip - That method still uses the Search Menu :(

Answer (score 1):

found the Answer on another site - simply open the Task manager and restart the windows explorer Processes ...this will fix the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! If you found an answer somewhere else please link to that page.

Answer (score 0):

You've set your Textsize to 200% or so.
Just go to the Settings and set it back to 100%.

[image: Textsize settings]